# Closing a modal created by angulajs ui modal service using javascript

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Background:**

I have a modal service used within my angularjs application. This service shows modals across my application and it works fine. Now I want to use the same modalservice to display a progressbar for me.

**Issue:**

I want to dynamically close the modal using javascript code (without any user clicks). I couldn't figure out how to do that.

So that the modal progressbar can be closed when the processing is completed. This involves no user clicks (all controlled by the system)

**ModalService Code:**

```
var modalService = function($modal,$sce){
var myModal;
         var modalDefaults = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true,
            templateUrl: '../ECommon/views/modal.html'
        };

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Close',
            actionButtonText: 'OK',
            headerText: 'Proceed?',
            bodyText: 'Perform this action?',
            showFooter: true
        };

        this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
            customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
            myModal = this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
            return myModal;
        };

        this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
            var tempModalDefaults = {};
            var tempModalOptions = {};

            //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service 
            angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

            //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
            angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

            if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
                tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                    $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.close(result);
                    };

                    $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };

                }
            }

            return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
        };
}
```

**Call from controller that triggers the dialog:**

```
$scope.logout = function(){
        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'W',
            actionButtonText: 'WLogout',
            headerText: 'Logout',
            bodyText: "<h1>WELCOME </h1>"
        };

        var modal = modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
         console.log(result);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dig into the [doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js) and found that you can use $modalStack service to close the opened modal anywhere :)

So use

```
$modalStack.dismiss("Close");
```

when your progress completes

PS:- Don't forgot to inject $modalStack in DI.

Comment: I tried putting the mentioned line into my code. but nothing happened.